# How to bubble custom jQuery event to window.document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have written an absolutely positioned drop-down menu.  I am triggering a custom event when this menu opens:

```
ps.DropDown.prototype._onOpenComplete = function() {
    $(this).trigger('MENU_OPEN', [this]);
}
```

This works great when I know which instance of ps.DropDown to target:

```
var dd = new ps.DropDown();
$(dd).on('MENU_OPEN', fn);
```

However, I would like for my custom event to bubble up to window.document if the event is not stopped from propagating.  For example:

```
var dd = new ps.DropDown();
$(dd).on('MENU_OPEN', function(event, instance) {
    // this would stop bubbling to $(window.document)
    // event.stopPropagation();
});
$(window.document).on('MENU_OPEN', function(event, instance) {
    // bubbled!
});
```

Is there any way to accomplish this with jQuery?

**EDIT to add a example by analogy**

A click on a button element will trigger an event.  This event will continue to bubble up the parent-element chain until it reaches window.document (unless propagation is stopped by an event listener).  I am interested in synthesizing this behavior for custom events such that if event.stopPropagation() is not called, it will bubble to window.document (or $.event, or some other window global, it doesn't matter)

Comment: Your code looks fine whoever have have subscribe to `MENU_OPEN` event should be triggered with `.trigger('MENU_OPEN)`.

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a reference to an instance of ps.DropDown.  I want the event to bubble to window.document.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for calling $.event.trigger manually:

```
$.event.trigger('myCustomEvent', someDataObj, someDomElement, false);
```

The last parameter is used for the "onlyHandlers" flag, false in this case as we want to trigger the elements handlers and then trigger again on each parentNode. In this fashion you can bind "myCustomEvent" to anything in between the window and the node where this event originated.

Comment: where is this documented?

Answer (score -1):

if I need custom events globally without a specific reference, I trigger the events on the body of the page

```
$('body').trigger('MENU_OPEN', [this]);
```

Now you can listen to that event anywhere without knowing anything about your DropDown

```
$('body').on('MENU_OPEN',function(event, dropDown){
    // bubbled
});
```

Never used the `window.document` as an event target.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm not trying to avoid using $(window.document).  For example, when I click a button, the click event bubbles into each parent until it hits window.document.  A listener on any parent element can potentially handle the event. I'm looking to replicate this for custom events.

Answer (score -1):

It's not neccessary to trigger custom events from a DOM element:

```
$(window.document).bind('dropDownHasOpened', function() {
   console.log($(this));
   // 'this' is window.document 
});

ps.DropDown.prototype._onOpenComplete = function() {
  $.event.trigger('dropDownHasOpened');
}
```

Comment: I understand it is not necessary.  In my example, I am not triggering on $(window.document) but on the DropDown instance.  I am interested in bubbling the event from that instance upward to $(window.document) similar to how a button click event will get bubbled through its parents to window.document.